# What's the best Mac custom disk image creation app?

Tags: macos, build-process, build-automation, disk-imaging

I'm looking for a custom disk image creation app that I can integrate into the build process for my app (which means I need to be able to run it from the command line if possible).

My desired features are that it will size the image for me, let me set the location of my icons when the image is opened, set a custom background/icon, etc.

Free would be nice but if there's something that does exactly what I need I'll pay for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DMG Canvas](http://www.araelium.com/dmgcanvas/) seems to do everything I need, including the ability to build from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can also hack together something using AppleScript. Here's a handy example.
[AppleScript example](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=AppleScript/2.1/en/as2039.html)